# The two teams shared the spoils with a 1–1 result

Tags: meaning

[image: screenshot of the definition of spoils]

What does this sentence mean? Especially" "with 1-1 result".

> The two teams shared the spoils with a 1–1 result.

Comment: If you replace "result" with "score" does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is apparently describing the result of a football (soccer) match.  The score was "one goal to one goal" or "1–1" (That is a dash, not a minus sign).

So the two teams tied, or "shared the victory" with a one-all score.

It could be another sport, but few other sports have such a low scoring rate as football.

Comment: Hi, do you mean the two teams got the benefits or profits by scoring a 1:1 result?